# Gather contents of src 'files' folder into versioned folder in the out directory

Tags: docpad

I would like to take all the contents of my 'files' folder, that's in my 'src' folder (js, css, image files etc), and add them to a folder in the out directory called, say, v001.

I could then version all my static assets on my Amazon S3 storage and only invalidate my html files when there are new changes (and archive the previous version of assets to save some space). I'd obviously add some management to the html document templates to pick the correct version of the assets.

Here's my src directory structure:

```
-src
   -files
        -fonts
        -img
        -scripts
        -styles

   -documents
            index.html.eco

   -layouts
           default.html.eco
```

And I want my out folder to look like this

```
-out
    -v001
         -fonts
         -img
         -scripts
         -styles

     index.html
```

I'm not sure how to gather the contents of my src 'files' folder and put them in the out directory in a folder called v001. Could anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

I would integrate grunt or gulp for such solution.
You could either use docpad plugins for grunt or gulp, or tools themselves.
For example there is a grunt plugin for copying files and folders: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy

I'm curious how would you do the invalidation

=====

Update. So what I just did and recommend to you.

- Install gulp in your docpad project: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/
- Install gulp docpad plugin: https://github.com/terminalpixel/docpad-plugin-gulp
- then install proper gulp plugin that will help you to copy files to a proper new folder.

As you can see from gulp docpad configuration, you can add this copy/paste action to the whole docpad build process - super awesome